# Issue with associated type conforming to a generic class in Swift

Tags: swift, swift-protocols, associated-types

I would like to define a protocol with an associated type which must be a subclass of a particular base class. Explicitly, suppose I have something like the following example.

```swift
class C<T> {
    init(arg: T) {}
}

class SC<T>: C<T> {}

protocol P {
    associatedtype A: C<Self>
    func foo(_ x: A)
}

struct D: P {
    typealias A = C<D>
    func foo(_ x: A) {}
}

struct E: P {
    typealias A = SC<E>
    func foo(_ x: A) {}
}
```

I would expect this code to compile correctly. Instead, I get the errors `Type 'D' does not conform to protocol 'P'` and `Type 'E' does not conform to protocol 'P'`. Xcode also provides the following messages: `Possibly intended match 'D.A' (aka 'C<D>') does not inherit from 'C<Self>'` and `Possibly intended match 'E.A' (aka 'SC<E>') does not inherit from 'C<Self>'`.

These errors do not make sense to me. In the first case, `C<D>` should be the same type as `C<Self>` and so `C<D>` should conform to `C<D> == C<Self>`. In the second case, `C<Self>` should be `C<E>` and so `SC<E>` should conform to `C<E> == C<Self>`. These are apparently not the case according to Xcode's messages.

Is this a compiler bug/problem with the error messages, or do I misunderstand how associated types work in this case?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's a problem with your understanding of associated types, so much as of generics. Generics are not covariant; there is no substitution principle for parameterized types. In other words, just because you can mentally slot `D` in place of `Self` doesn't mean you can substitute `C<D>` for `C<Self>`. They are different types (unrelated).

Here's a simple counterexample to show you what I mean:

```
class C<T> {
    init(arg: T) {}
}
class Cat {}
class Kitten : Cat {}
```

Now let's try to use a `C<Kitten>` where a `C<Cat>` is expected:

```
var c1 = C(arg:Cat())
var c2 = C(arg:Kitten())
c1 = c2 // error
```

I suspect that *that* is what you think should work. It doesn't. For the same reason, your belief that "`C<D>` should be the same type as `C<Self>`" is wrong.

To make this a bit more relevant to your actual example, consider this trivial case. This compiles:

```
class C<T> {
    init(arg: T) {}
}
protocol P {
    associatedtype A: C<Any>
    func foo(_ x: A)
}
struct D: P {
    func foo(_ x: C<Any>) {}
}
```

But this does not compile:

```
class C<T> {
    init(arg: T) {}
}
protocol P {
    associatedtype A: C<Any>
    func foo(_ x: A)
}
struct D: P {
    func foo(_ x: C<String>) {}
}
```

Well, String is an Any, you might say, so why doesn't this compile? It's because that fact is irrelevant; there is no substitution principle for the parameterized type in a generic.

Comment: Of course I could be wrong about where the mistake lies, in which case I'll just delete this. It's hard reading someone else's mind! Apologies if I'm not putting my finger on the issue.

Comment: This answer is awesome and very explanatory, but I'm still confused. I now understand why generics shouldn't be covariant, but I guess I'm thinking of `Self` as a typealias for whatever class is implementing the protocol. That is, I think that a `C<D>` is a `C<Self>` not because `D` conforms to `Self` but because `D` _literally is_ `Self`. What is `Self` if not a typealias for `D`?

Comment: In particular, if `class C<T> {}` and `protocol P { init(_ x: C<Self>) }`, why can I write `struct A: P { init(_ x: C<A>) {} }` without error if `C<Self>` and `C<A>` are different types?